# How to update TextView with CountdownTimer onResume?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to use a Countdown Timer but have a problem. If i start it and then press a Back button (change lifecycle to onStop) and return back to activity - i cant see timer values in TextView. But in Logcat i see that the timer works.

Question: how to update TextView after return on activity (onResume)

***UPDATE.***
While i'll not close activity this code works as it should - well. But if i press back button there is no values in TextView.
The timer method code (this method is called from onCreate):

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(rest + 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                secondsUntilFinish = Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                String minutes = String.format("%02d",TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(secondsUntilFinish));
                String seconds = String.format("%02d",TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(secondsUntilFinish) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(secondsUntilFinish)));
                tvRoutineTimer.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.exercise_rest_timer, minutes, seconds));
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onTick = " + getResources().getString(R.string.exercise_rest_timer, minutes, seconds));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tvRoutineProgress.setText(getString(R.string.routine_progress, currentStep, totalSteps));
                tvRoutineTimer.setText(getString(R.string.exercise_rest_timer, "00", "00"));
                notificationAfterRest();
                btnExerciseDone.setText(getString(R.string.button_exercise_done));
                btnExerciseDone.setEnabled(true);
                tvExercisePlaceholder.setText(getString(R.string.exercise_current_title));
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: It'll be far easier to help if you post some of your code.

Comment: @Pztar, done. say if u need to see more

Comment: What are you seeing on your `TextView`? The old values or nothing at all?

Comment: @Pztar, it shows me end value from finish. `tvRoutineTimer ("00:00");`

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your `TextView` from the UI thread. Update your `TextView` like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvRoutineTimer.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.exercise_rest_timer, minutes, seconds));
        });
```

Place the `runOnUiThread` inside the `onTick()`

Comment: But if I need to display values every second, is it OK to call `runOnUiThread` method so often?

Comment: Yes, all you're doing is updating the UI. `runOnUiThread` is the short quick answer. Using a `Handler` with a `Runnable` would be better.

Comment: pls check out post update. At 1st pic. timer works well, at second - timer shows only in Logcat but nothing in UI. runOnUiThread() method doesnt help.
***
In logcat "the exercise activity onStart() blah blah" show after returning to activity. As u can mention - it instantly jumps to onFinish() in CountDownTimer

Comment: if i use Handler with Runnable then a get a new threads with different values after each re-open of activity

Comment: CountDownTimer creates a Handler that is associated with the Looper for the thread on which CountDownTimer is constructed.  So long as the CountDownTimer is constructed on the main thread, the callbacks are guaranteed to also be invoked on the main thread and no special runOnUiThread logic is needed.  Since the original poster stated he creates the CountDownTimer from onCreate, he'll already be getting the callbacks invoked on the main thread.